# Calculate the differences in a List in a functional way

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming

I have a list of absolute values (for example: 10, 50, 30), which I'd like to transform in a functional way to a list of differences between these numbers. So, given an input as `10, 50, 30`, I'd like the outcome to be: `40, -20`.

For context: my current implementation is just a for loop which keeps track of the previous value, calculates the difference, and adds it a new list, but I was wondering how this can be solved in a more functional way? (I'm using Kotlin, but a solution in Java would be fine too)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`zipWithNext`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html).

You pass in a lambda taking 2 parameters. `zipWithNext` will go through the list and pass each pair of elements to your lambda. To compute the difference, simply subtract:

```
val list = listOf(10, 50, 30)
val result = list.zipWithNext { a, b -> b - a }
```

Comment: I think, it should be `val result = list.zipWithNext { a, b -> b - a }`

Comment: Ah, zipping, I didn't know about that one, I was looking into reduce/folds! Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @ErikPragt in case you didn't know, ``zip`` usually takes two (sometimes more) collections and hands you an element from each, so it's a good way to combine and work with things that are related. ``zipWithNext`` is a special case that uses the same collection to give you pairs from the sequence, but ``zip`` is a good one to know in general! There's also ``windowed`` if you want that sliding window over one collection, but with more than two items (it's less convenient than ``zipWithNext`` though)

Comment: @cactustictacs I knew about zip, thought I didn't know you could apply it like `zipWithNext` on the same collection, but I didn't know about `windowed`, and I am not sure what the use case for that would be. Would you have an example?

Comment: @ErikPragt yeah you could just do ``stuff.zip(stuff.drop(1)) { a, b -> whatever }``, it's just two iterators you're zipping together, but ``zipWithNext`` is a common use case so they've done it for you. ``windowed`` is more powerful because you can handle more elements at once, and control the step too. So you could, say, do a ``zipWithNextTwo`` thing with ABC, BCD, CDE etc (maybe to calculate a rolling average) or handle a collection in chunks with a step the size of the window, ABCD, EFGH etc (there's a simple function called ``chunked`` too but you have less control over that)